# Is this the right way to use TcpListener in the background?

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a server application using `TcpListener` in `BackgroundWorker`, where my application is doing some work, and in the background listening to a IP:PORT.

The `DoWork` of the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true) //infinit loop : listen
    {
        var clientSocket = _serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        e.Result = clientSocket;
        m_oWorker.ReportProgress(1, clientSocket);
    }
}
```

At the progress change event, I do notify the form (launcher of the `BackgroundWorker`) that a new `TcpClient` is available:

The `ProgressChanged` of the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _luncher.NotifyFormNewTcpClient((TcpClient)e.UserState);
    MessageBox.Show("new TcpClient Connected...");
}
```

Now for each form that wants to use that background worker, I need to add the method `NotifyFormNewTcpClient`, and in that method, I have a list of `TcpListening`, and I added the returned TcpClient to that list:

```
public void NotifyFormNewTcpClient(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    TcpClientsList.Add(tcpClient);
    lNumberOfClient.Text = TcpClientsList.Count.ToString()  " Clients";
}
```

**Question:**

What I am doing works until now, but I wanted to know if I am doing it the right way.  I want my application to keep doing some work, while it's listening in a LAN for clients that request it, and have a list of the clients (TcpClient) at any moment.  Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK, though I think there is some redundant code - `e.Result = clientSocket;` is never used, since work is never completed...

You might also want to consider a different approach to `BackgroundWorker` - `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync`. Instead of creating a worker thread you can do this:

```
private Task<TcpClient> listen() {

   return _serverSocket.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ContinueWith(clientSocket => {
       _launcher.NotifyFormNewTcpClient(clientSocket);
       MessageBox.Show("new TcpClient Connected...");
       return listen();
   });
```